# What will be the best ARIA for a select control that displays a specified quantity of form fieldsets?

Tags: accessibility

I have a select control that a user will use to display a specified quantity of form fieldsets (like, "How many fieldsets do you need?"). I don't have a lot of control over the form structure, which uses an UL with 1 LI per form input - some LIs are hidden then become visible based upon the value of the select. I'm thinking of setting aria-controls="id of UL" on the select, and introducing a text element with attributes aria-live="polite" and role="status" - then updating this element's text to describe the quantity of fieldsets available. Thoughts?

Nathaniel asked for a code example - here's the basic HTML (I can't modify the list structure but I can modify everything else via JS):

```
        <ul id="myform">
        <li><select aria-controls="myform"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
        <div role="status" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" id="statusMsg">This text will announce how many fieldsets are now visible</div></li>
        <li class="fieldset1"><input type="text"></li>
        <li class="fieldset1"><input type="text"></li>
        <li class="fieldset2"><input type="text"></li>
        <li class="fieldset2"><input type="text"></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Please post some code so we can review this question more effectively.

Comment: Hi @NathanielFlick I added some example HTML to show the structure I need to work around.

Comment: You say you can't change the list structure, does that include the positions of the `<select>` and `aria-live` region as those are going to cause issues being a part of the `<ul>`. If you can move them outside the list then it becomes much easier

Comment: @GrahamRitchie the list structure comes from a 3rd party forms module for our CMS (I want to avoid major surgery). I'm injecting the aria-live region so it can be anywhere - I'll test it with NVDA. I suppose I'm just wondering if my approach is sound or if another technique is better?

Comment: The code looks ok as is.  All `<li>` elements are direct children of the `<ul>`.  The `<select>` is a child of the `<li>`, which is also ok, from an html parsing perspective.  Note that `role="status"` gives you an implicit "polite" and atomic so you don't need those two attributes.  https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#status